# How to evaluate functions at each points in matlab

Tags: matlab

There are two types of problem I need to solve, we have a function of two variables f(x,y):
one is x, y are vector with same length, how to evaluate function at each (x_i,y_i). In first dimension, it is simply f(x). How to achieve this in two dimension.

The other is evaluate values for each point of the mesh formed by x and y i.e.,
evaluate at each point (x_i,y_j) for every (i,j)

Comment: You need to be much more specific. What sort of functions? What have you tried so far? Have you done any research of your own?

Comment: For a general function with two variables

Comment: The Matlab documentation/help centre has so many examples of this, have you read any?

Comment: Why can't you define a function that takes two inputs, then use element-wise operators (`.*, ./, .^`, etc.) on both inputs?  The same applies for a grid of values.

Comment: thanks, I will try, But is there a way to do like vectorization?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about.  I can't really answer your question until you provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, can you clarify? I guess I see the first dimension case, but I don't get what you mean by 2 dimensions.

As for the mesh, it should be solved as follows. cartprod.m is my custom cartesian product function found [here](http://pastebin.com/xBDz2yZZ).

```
% Define Test Data
x = 1:5;
y = 2:4;

% Define Test Function
f = @(x,y) x*y;

% Permutate x/y as a grid
s = sortrows( cartprod(x,y) , 1 );

% Apply function for each permutation
a = arrayfun( f, s(:,1), s(:,2) );

% Reshape into matrix
M = reshape( a, 5, [] )   % Solution here
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood and please clarify the first half of the question for me!

Comment: That `arrayfun` call is unnecessary. You can just use `.*`in the function and just simply the vectors directly into `f`. It's much faster too.

Comment: Well in my case it is, but my method is for a more complex function which can't be easily vectorized. The OP stated "For a general function with two variables" :)

Comment: Really? What's wrong with `f = @(x,y) x.*y;`, then `a = f(s(:,1),s(:,2));`?

Comment: Ah I see.  Fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

In addition to other solutions, If you define the function with vector properties, the rest would be easy.

example:

```
function f = myfunc(x)
%% x is a vector or matrix including y,z,.. vectors
%
f = (1 + ((x(:,1) + x(:,2) + 1).^2);
```

Then easily evaluate your function as follows:

```
X = [1 1;2 3;1 -1];    % consider this your input data
f(X);
```

---

**2.**

Additionally, if you do not want to define it separately, the function can be defined also in the spot:

```
f = @(x)(1 + ((x(:,1) + x(:,2) + 1).^2);
f(X)
```